# Adwords csv file in attachment is not parsing properly

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use google apps script to extract data from an email attachment which is basically an Adwords report as csv file.

Here is the gist of the code

```
var dataTest3 = Utilities.parseCsv(msg.getAttachments()[0].getDataAsString());
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(1, 1, dataTest3.length, dataTest3[0].length).setValues(dataTest3);
```

`msg` is the `GmailMessage` object.

The result that i am getting is an array with strange format

[image]

The data shows ok but its value is strange

[image]

Any idea how can i make it parse into the spreadsheet like a normal csv. It opens up like a normal csv when downloaded.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The description *basically an Adwords report as csv file* needs to be investigated... what *exactly* is the file format? With only pictures of your problem, the best I can do is guess that your file is using some custom delimiter, not commas.

"CSV" stands for *Comma* Separated Values, but in practice it applies to text files with a number of different field delimiters - call them [Delimiter-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values). Common delimiters include commas (`,`), tabs (`\t`), colons (`:`), v-bars (`|`), and sometimes just spaces (usually between quote-enclosed text fields).

Instead of using the version of [`Utilities.parseCsv(csv)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv) that assumes a comma delimiter, you can use [`Utilities.parseCsv(csv, delimiter)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv-delimiter) to specify a custom delimiter. You should be able to determine what the delimiter is by reviewing the attachment in the debugger.

You could also try adapting `importFromCSV()` from [How to Import tab-delimited "CSV"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679048/how-to-import-tab-delimited-csv/24684621#24684621), which automatically detects tab or comma delimiters.